# Access a var inside which is inside a function from another function in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, function, variables

I made this code and it showed up an error. I want to access a variable which is inside a function from another function. This is the JavaScript code:

```
function TestOne() {
    var Words = ["Hola", "Adios"]
    var Number = Math.floor((Math.random() * 2));
    var RandomWord = Words[Number];
    console.log(RandomWord);
}

function TestTwo() {
    console.log(RandomWord)
}
```

And this is the **body html** code (I already linked the js file in the html):

```
    <input type="button" onclick="TestOne()" value="TestOne">
    <input type="button" onclick="TestTwo()" value="TestTwo">
```

In the console it's show an error:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: RandomWord is not defined
> at TestTwo (Main.js:9)
> at HTMLInputElement.onclick (Main.html:12)

Comment: You cannot do this. You will have to declare your variable outside the function.

Answer (score 0):

Just declare the RandomWord var outside any function and make it global, then you will have access to it from any function:

```
var RandomWord = "";

function TestOne() {
   var Words = ["Hola", "Adios"]
   var Number = Math.floor((Math.random() * 2));
   RandomWord = Words[Number];
   console.log(RandomWord);
}
function TestTwo() {
   console.log(RandomWord)
}
```